# Compare database on Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, oracle10g

I am working on a project which migrates databases from Oracle 10g to SQL Server 2008 using SSMA(SQL SERVER MIGRATION ASSISTANT). I want to know if there is a way to actually compare the data in tables that resides on a table space say 'A' on ORACLE with the corresponding migrated database 'A' on SQL SERVER.

I am not bothered about the data types of various columns right now.If there is a way to map it then it will be great. I am just concerned with the data difference if any that exists.

Let me know if you are aware of any such free tool which does so, or any of you have written a tool which can help me out to do the same.

Thanks !!

Comment: You can't possibly care about the data and not the datatypes. A date as a string is completely different from a date as a date.

Comment: @Ben:I understand that but my motive here is entirely different. I want to check and ensure that data is correct. To ensure that data type mapping is consistent with what I want I can write a script to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to map the PK from the source to the destination and if the colu,ns are the same, fetch a bulk and compare...

Lots of hard work.

Maybe it will be better if you could count rows and verify a statistic group of records.